I am having trouble accessing the file type of a file uploaded on the front-end by the user
I want to create a different folder for every fileType using the multer module. However, The fileType constant variable seems to be undefined in the multer disk storage, whereas it is correctly caught when I access in the .post middleware function:
app.post('/storeOnHDD', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // outputs the file and the file type
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded');
    }

    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        file: req.file,
    });
})

Client side app
const formData = new FormData()

        console.log(file)
        formData.append('file', file)
        formData.append('fileType', 'video')

        axios.post('http://localhost:5000/storeOnHDD', formData, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            },
        })
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res.data)
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err)
            })

Server side app
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const multer = require('multer')
const fs = require('fs')

const app = express();
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())

Create a directory specified by the fileType
// create a directory if it doesn't already exists using the file system module
const createDirIfNotExists = (dir) => {
    if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
        fs.mkdirSync(dir, { recursive: true })
    }
}

Multer Storage
// set storage engine for multer
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, cb) => {
        const fileType = req.body.fileType
        const uploadPath = `./uploads/${fileType}`

        createDirIfNotExists(uploadPath)

        cb(null, uploadPath)
    },
    filename: (req, file, cb) => {
        cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

app.post middleware
app.post('/storeOnHDD', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body) // here we receive the file and the fileType correctly
    if (!req.file) {
        return res.status(400).send('No file uploaded');
    }

    res.status(200).send({
        message: 'File uploaded successfully',
        file: req.file,
    });
})

My folder output

Expected output
A different folder for every file type

Why are you passing the fileType as a different variable? Why don't you retrieve the correct filetype from the uploaded file?

Does this answer your question? Req.body not available in multer.diskStorage(). Error Property body doesn't exist on type 'Request'

It's because fileType field has not been processed yet, and that's why it's undefined.
On client, change the order of fields, and add fileType field to the form before file field:
// add fileType first
formData.append('fileType', 'video')
formData.append('file', file)

axios.post('http://localhost:5000/storeOnHDD', formData, {

see:

Note that req.body might not have been fully populated yet. It depends
on the order that the client transmits fields and files to the server.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#diskstorage

@DarkBee I explained the problem clearly enough, there was no need for it

Yes there was, otherwise I wouldn't have commented for more clarification right? At least now you have provided a source
